# Which JAR contains AppservPasswordLoginModule in GlassFish 3.1

Tags: glassfish, osgi, realm

I want to develop a custom realm for GlassFish 3.1 in NetBeans 7.0.1, and I want to import the JAR that contains the class `com.sun.appserv.security.AppservPasswordLoginModule` to the project classpath, so I could extend it. Tried `\glassfish-3.1\glassfish\lib\appserv-rt.jar`, but it's not in that. Which JAR do I have to import?

Comment: Please clarify your question I don't get what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
glassfish/modules/security.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Maven for that it's easier than pasting jars.

If you need to past Jars go to glassfish repo below and copy your jar from there.

This dependency is this one

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>security</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

and repo

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>glassfish</id>
        <name>Glassfish</name>
        <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/glassfish</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Cheers !

Comment: Well, never used Maven until now. I guess I will have to give it a shot. Thanks.